# Website is not loading properly with HTTPS

Tags: css, .htaccess, ssl, https

I want to apply HTTPS on some selected pages of my website.
I tried doing that using .htaccess file but after that my site is not getting loaded properly. After HTTPS, my site is looking like it does not have CSS. Please help.

Comment: Are you using the full path URL for your CSS? If it's full URL is not HTTPS, but is HTTP that could be getting blocked. If you change to relative paths, it should work ok.

Comment: Thanks, @WF4 your suggestion worked.

Comment: That's great @Nancy I have added my comments an as answer for you so that you can mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here will be because of the way browsers block traffic from non-secure domains. 
When you use the full URL for your content e.g. images, css, scripts. if you transfer to a secure domain e.g. `https://` then anything using a `http://` prefix will not be allowed as it will not have been transferred securely.

So, what you need to do here is to use relative paths when including your content. So instead of using `http://www.domain.com/cssfile.css` you would instead use `/cssfile.css`. So if your site IS using `http://` then the content will be transferred using that protocol, but when you switch to the login page for instance which uses `https://` the content will still get delivered, but instead using the secure protocol.